# TYPO3 static_info_tables -> Table 'db_name.tx_staticinfotables_domain_model_currency' doesn't exist

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

We use **sr_feuser_register** for user registration. This requires the **static_info_tables** extension.
Unfortunately after the upgrade of static_info_tables the frontend pages with the Frontend User Registreation plugin keep giving the same error: "Table 'dbname.tx_staticinfotables_domain_model_currency' doesn't exist".
The table mapping is well configured as below:

```
SJBR\StaticInfoTables\Domain\Model\Currency {
    mapping {
        tableName = static_currencies
        columns {
            cu_decimal_digits.mapOnProperty = decimalDigits
            cu_decimal_point.mapOnProperty = decimalPoint
            cu_sub_divisor.mapOnProperty = divisor
            cu_iso_3.mapOnProperty = isoCodeA3
            cu_iso_nr.mapOnProperty = isoCodeNumber
            cu_name_en.mapOnProperty = nameEn
            cu_sub_name_en.mapOnProperty = subdivisionNameEn
            cu_sub_symbol_left.mapOnProperty = subdivisionSymbolLeft
            cu_sub_symbol_right.mapOnProperty = subdivisionSymbolRight
            cu_symbol_left.mapOnProperty = symbolLeft
            cu_symbol_right.mapOnProperty = symbolRight
            cu_thousands_point.mapOnProperty = thousandsPoint
            deleted.mapOnProperty = deleted
        }
    }
}
```

...and the typoscript is included properly.

The static_info_tables versions <= 6.3.10 work well.
The static_info_tables versions >= 6.4.0 throw the error above.
The sr_feuser_register versions used here were 5.0.0 and 5.1.0.

Does someone have any idea?
Maybe I missed something?

Comment: Did you try the "compare database" option in install tool, to check all the tables?

Comment: Yes, I did. It doesn't report any difference. The 'static_currencies' table is present and has the appropriate columns.

Comment: Did you got the fix ?

Comment: No. No fix yet. We just kept the 6.3.10 version installed.